# Add cover art to opus file using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, metadata, opus

I'm trying to embed a cover art to an .opus (ogg container) audio file. I'm aware ffmpeg recently added support for that function according to this ticket:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4448

Tried with multiple command parameters but so far i haven't been successful, even thought i'm using the latest ffmpeg build for windows. These for example don't work:

> ffmpeg -i original.opus -i image.png -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c copy -metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (front)" out.opus

output: [opus @ 00000000006fe140] Unsupported codec id in stream 1
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:1

> ffmpeg -i original.opus -i image.png -map_metadata 0 -c copy out.opus

resulting file doesn't have cover.

Comment: The ticket is still open; it hasn't been implemented.

Comment: @Gyan what does the last comment mean? (i'm not familiar with Trac)

Comment: The last comment is "Summary: Properly support cover art in ogg → Support writing album cover art in ogg / opus" which is just a notice that the title was changed.